# ElasticSearch query with MUST and SHOULD

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query to get data from AWS elasticSearch instance v6.2

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {"logLevel": "error"}
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                            "match": {"EventCategory": "Home Management"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [{
            "range": { "timestamp": { "gte": 155254550880 }}    
            }
        ]
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0
}
```

My data has multiple EventCategories for example 'Home Management' and 'User Account Management'. Problem with this is inside `should` having `match` returns all data because phrase 'Management' is in both categories. If I use `term` instead of `match`, it don't returns anything at all even when the given value is exactly same as in document.

I need to get data when any of given category is matched with rest of filters.

EDIT:
There may none, one or more than one `EventCategory` be passed to `should` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you added a `should` within a `must`. Do you expect to have more than one `should` cases? It looks a bit odd.

As for your question, you can't use the `term` query on an analysed field, but only on `keyword` typed fields. If your `EventCategory` field has the default mapping, you can run the `term` query against the default non-analysed multi-field of `EventCategory` as follows:

```
...
{
  "term": { "EventCategory.keyword": "Home Management" }
}
...
```

Furthermore, if you just want to filter in/out documents without caring about their relevance, I'd recommend you to move all the conditions in the `filter` block, to speed-up your query and make a better use of the cache.

Comment: Yes, there may be one and more then one `should` cases.

It look like, following your approach returns fine result. Let me try more cases

Comment: Glad it helped. Have you checked more cases? Is your question answered? - please let me know if you need further clarifications about my consideration on using filters

Comment: It definitely helped, I am marking it as accepted but I do want to know more about this scenario. Any article or documentation?

Comment: Sure, you can find something here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-filter-context.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @glenacota. I just sent you connect invitation on LinkedIn. Please accept and stay connected. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work.

I've just removed `should` and created two `must` clauses one for each of `event` and `management`. Note that  the query is meant for `text` datatypes.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "logLevel":"error"
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "EventCategory":"home"
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "EventCategory":"management"
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "timestamp":{  
                     "gte":155254550880
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":10,
   "from":0
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to answer the question. I didn't try it but the answer by @glenacota helped and solved my problem.